# Capturar posible error en una consulta y async/await

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, sequelize.js

estoy intentando lanzar una consulta que funciona sin el bloque if, pero me gustaría capturar si hubiese algún error, os dejo el código y el error de consola.

```
    // Almaceno una nueva receta
    exports.storeRecipe = async (req, res, error) => {
    
        const recipe = await Recipe.create(req.body);
        if (!recipe.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Error`);
        } else {
             await res.status(200).json({
                success: 'Añadida nueva receta'
            });
        }
    
    };
Servidor arrancado en http://localhost:8090.
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `recipes`;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `recipes`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recipes` (`id` INTEGER auto_increment , `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `ingredient` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `time` INTEGER NOT NULL, `step` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `recipes`
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (`id` INTEGER auto_increment , `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `users`
Tablas sincronizadas
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `recipes` (`id`,`name`,`ingredient`,`time`,`step`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?);
(node:152257) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at exports.storeRecipe (/home/luis/cursoDaw/DWES/nodejs/crud-token/back/controllers/recipesController.js:21:48)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:152257) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:152257) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Podrías envolver tu código con un bloque [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch)

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente con un try...catch se soluciona, dejo el código por si sirve en un futuro.

```
// Almaceno una nueva receta
exports.storeRecipe = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const recipe = await Recipe.create(req.body);
        res.status(200).json({
            success: 'Añadida nueva receta',
            message: recipe
        });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: 'error',
            message: error
        });
    }
};
```